# How to pass an intent to my App without drawing the Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

I'm implementing a simple App that can receive 'share's from the YouTube App and simply sends it to a server.

I'm able to pass the `Intent` to a `ShareActivity` I've implemented, but every time I share a video from YouTube, it opens the `ShareActivity`.

Since the user doesn't need to interact with the App while sharing, I'd like to remove this phase entirely. That is, I'd like to receive the `Intent` from Youtube and **process it in the background** without any hassle to the user.

I'm thinking of creating an `IntentService` that can handle such incoming Intents, but I'm not sure how to proceed. (Is this the right way to achieve this? If so, from where should I start the `IntentService`?, Will it be able to receive Intents if the user kills my app?)

I can't seem to find any resources on the Internet regarding this. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: Okay, This is a minimal, not-working example. I hope this can help you guys guide me better. Cause I'm stuck.

### Android Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.blumonkey.versatyl">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".ShareService"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>

    </service>
</application>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.blumonkey.versatyl;

import android.content.Intent; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, ShareService.class);
        startService(msgIntent);
    } 
}
```

### ShareService.java

```
package com.blumonkey.versatyl;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Customize class - update intent actions and extra parameters.
 */
public class ShareService extends IntentService {
    public ShareService() {
        super("ShareService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Log.d("Msg:", "Got Intent!");
    }
}
```

[image: The <code>IntentChooser</code> that I see when I try to share a video on my AVD]

The only message that I see in the Log is when the MainActivity sends the Intent to the service to start it.

Answer (score 0):

`IntentService` would be fine, or even a regular `Service` if you will need to use resources for long period of time - you just need to add an `IntentFilter` with the proper filter options to the service in the manifest.

The Android docs explain it for both `Activities` and `Service`s:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Sometimes an `Intent` is designed to be handled by an `Activity` so just be cautious about that.

And this is the correct way to "wake up" your app if a user "kills" it. An `Intent` that your app is designed to handle will receive it. However, sometimes users can set preferred apps to handled certain `Intent`s, in which case you do not have control over what happens.

Comment: How do I know what Intents are designed to be handled by an Activity?

Comment: It is usually in the documentation for the Intent, but sometimes you just have to test it.

Comment: I have added a few snippets. I have intent filters set in the manifest file, but I still cant see my app in the IntentChooser. Thanks!

Comment: this is not actually related to your question - you asked if you could receive an Intent without launching an Activity.. now you want a Service listed in a Chooser for an Intent. Choosers are usually selected to launch an app, which means an Activity must be the target for the Intent. If you are wanting that kind of behavior you can have an empty Activity that forwards the Intent to your service, but you should probably ask that as a separate question.